# How can I Deserialize an object with BsonSerializer.Deserialize?

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I tried to manually implement serialization classes according to Mongo's official document http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/bson/serialization/

But the program shows "Stack overflow." and exits.

```cs
public class JobSerializer : SerializerBase<Job>
{
    public override Job Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bytes = context.Reader.ReadBytes();
        return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Job>(bytes);
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Job value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteBytes(value.ToBson());
    }
}
```

Comment: The serializer for `Job` is `JobSerializer`, so `BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Job>(bytes);` will delegate that task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, which will delegate the task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, which will delegate the task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, which will delegate the task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, which will delegate the task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, which will delegate the task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, which will delegate the task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, which will delegate the task to `JobSerializer.Deserialize`, and so on...

Comment: You're very welcome.